# Tpl file for layered navigation module is prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop and I would want to remove availability column from layered navigation module from prestashop.
Please let me know the name of the tpl file or any other alternative method for it..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

go to your backoffice->modules->layerednavigation...& then configure it...you can enable & disable options from there